# Querying a HIVE Table from SQL Server 2016 or later

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to query my Hortonworks cluster Hive tables from SQL Server. My scenario below:

- HDP 2.6, Ambari, HiveServer2
- SQL Server 2016 Enterprise
- Kerberos configuration for secure logins in HDP

I was reading about the PolyBase service in SQL Server 2016 and I suppose later versions. However, I realize that according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/get-started-with-polybase) what this service is going to perform in SQL Server is a bridge to reach out my HDFS and recreate external tables based in this data source.

Otherwise what I'm expecting is query Hive objects like these would be SQL Server objects as well, such as a linked server.

Someone has an example or knows if this is possible within SQL Server and Hive?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to querying Hive from SQL server, you can download ODBC driver (Microsoft or [Hortonsworks](https://de.hortonworks.com/downloads/)) and create a Data Source Name (DSN) for Hive. In **Advanced** option check **Use Native Query**. Then just create new linked server in the SQL server with the same name of datasource as Data Source Name in ODBC driver.

Write openquery something like:

```
select top 100 * from 
    openquery(HadoopLinkedServer,
              'column1, column2 from databaseInHadoop.tableInHadoop')
```